# Seams are obvious in blender but invisible in Substance Painter. How to mitigate seam visibility?

Tags: modeling, shaders

**`SUBSTANCE PAINTER`**
[image]
**`BLENDER MATERIAL PREVIEW`**
[image]

I'm quite curious to know why substance painter can completely hide my UV seams whilst in Blender, the seams are overwhelmingly obvious.

What can I do to mitigate such obvious seams in blender?

Comment: Make sure to use the correct normal map, for Blender is Open GL, by default substance uses Direct X

Comment: Normal map format is already OpenGL

Comment: Then, you need to explain more about your setup, your textures, your material node tree, to have a better view of everyting that you make to help you in a better way. The more info, the better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The seams being visible were caused by the normal map. All that was required to fix the problem was to correctly set the color space as *Non-Color* instead of *sRGB*

[image]